# Conflict between multiple "android-support-v4" libraries

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I import 2 external libraries (library A, and library B) into my project in Eclipse. These libraries both need "android-support-v4.jar" library. So when compiling, it caused error:

```
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

I've read all similar questions, and did try to delete the library "androi-support-v4.jar" from my project. Follow the instruction: Properties-> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Select "android-support-v4.jar" -> all buttons are disable. I cannot delete it ???

[image]

Even, in the case I could delete "android-support-v4.jar" from my project, there is still a conflict between 2 libraries A and B. Because both A and B need "android-support-v4.jar". If I delete "android-support-v4.jar" from library A so library A cannot be compiled.

Comment: Delete this jar from your project hierarchy. Then just copy other one here and add from properties.Be sure they are both are same Jars. Did you try this ?

Comment: Delete it out the /libs/ folder

Comment: I did delete "android-support-v4.jar" from my project. But there is still conflict between 2 libraries A and B. If I delete "android-support-v4.jar" from Library A (delete it out the libs/ folder), library A cannot be compiled as I said

Comment: @SercanOzdemir: you are right. I will update my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks @SercanOzdemir for your answer. The solution is my project and all dependencies libraries must infer to only one "android-support-v4.jar". So what I do is

- In my project, I add "android-support-v4.jar" from Library A
- In the library B, I delete its jar, and also add "android-support-v4.jar" from Library A

So all infer to only one "android-support-v4.jar" from Library A

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new library project with the SupportLibrary jar file, and have all your projects which need the support library refer it. This way, you just have to manage 1 copy of the jar. Just make sure you do a clean build every time you update the support library.

You can always keep a common copy of the SupportLibrary and have all projects add that as an external jar in the build path. But it doesn't let you update the library as quickly as you could by creating a project out of it.

*PS: When you create the SupportLibrary project make sure you don't include any resources as part of it. Usually eclipse creates values-v11/styles.xml and values-v14/styles.xml when you create a new project. This might cause the build to fail when another library project includes your SupportLibrary project (espcially if it targets APIs below Honeycomb).*